# Чем являются выделенные фрагменты с синтаксической точки зрения?

Tags: синтаксис

Помогите, пожалуйста, у меня снова сложности с определением синтаксической роли (к сожалению мне не знакомы такие обороты и конструкции).

1. *Убью его, **к чертовой матери**.*
2. *Да говори уже, **черт возьми**!*
3. *Да уж, друг, **тут ной не ной**, не поможет.*
4. *Она раздраженно помотала головой: **отстань, мол**.*
5. *Я хотела сделать их счастливыми – **скольких смогу**.*

Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) Убью его, к чертовой матери.**

Фразеологические выражения со словом"черт" в русском языке весьма многочисленны,  и они могут выполнять различные функции. **Иди к чертовой матери** - это"убирайся" прочь, очень далеко, в неизвестность. Здесь нет обособления, оборот используется в значении наречия. **Убью его, к чертовой матери** - это междометное выражение  чувства  (убью, а там будь что будет). **Какие, к чертовой матери, переправы?** Здесь тоже междометие, оценка ситуации. Таким образом, всё фразеологическое пространство "черта и его матери" мыслится как **неизвестное и гиблое** место.

2) **Да говори уже, черт возьми!** Но как, чёрт возьми, это сделать? Чёрт возьми, как же его звали? Чёрт возьми, мы хорошо поработали! Это  междометное сочетание, выражающие самые разнообразные чувства (нетерпение, удивление, раздражение и даже удовлетворение).

3) **Да уж, друг, тут ной не ной, не поможет.**  Здесь, скорее всего, оборот со значением обобщенной уступки: сколько ни плачь, всё напрасно, результата нет. Сравнить:  Плачь, не плачь, а делать дело нужно. Плачь не плачь, назад не вернешь, — сказала старушка.

4)  **Она раздраженно помотала головой: отстань, мол.** Мол - вводное слово (от молвить), в данном случае слово "мол" переводит жест в реплику.

5) **Я хотела сделать их счастливыми – скольких смогу.**  Присоединительная конструкция, аналог местоименного придаточного. Сравнить: Я хотела сделать  счастливыми стольких, сколько я  смогу.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за время и труд! Ценю очень!!! Только в номере (4) меня интересует всё, что стоит после двоеточия. Это тоже какая-то присоединительная конструкция?

Comment: Это БСП (бессоюзное сложное предложение), двоеточие ставится, если вторая часть поясняет первую. Второе предложение является односоставным (определенно-личным), сказуемое выражено глаголом в повелительном наклонении